# Contenload taglib in opencms 8.5.1

Tags: opencms

I am new at OpenCMS 8.5.1.
My problem is that I want to get all pages in folder(ex:new-releases).
I can get all page in this folder by using  taglib but I want to get only pages with the property isShowed = true.
How can't I filter this condition.I also use .It works but I can't paging if I use .
I think maybe I can custom  to add a condition "isShowed == true" in this taglib.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can access resource properties using the ${cms:...} jstl-function. Here an example:

```
${cms:vfs(pageContext).property['/index.html']['Title']}
```

There are more examples in their documentation http://www.opencms.org/javadoc/core/org/opencms/jsp/util/CmsJspVfsAccessBean.html